# How to properly add personal repos to a newly created organization

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I am interested in creating a *GitHub Organization Account*. I'd like to host a few of my existing personal repos on this new account in order to benefit from some of it's account type features, and add a layer of professionalism to these projects. But I do not know exactly how this - "transfer of repos" should be done.

There are several ways to "Move/Migrate" repos, but I would like to use a convention that is "Industry Standard" among companies hosting public repos.

I know that Github allows users to **import** repositories to new accounts. From what I've learned, this method does not change the original account, and all history of the repository is simply copied to the new account.

Repos can also be **transferred** to a new account. This method also does several things for you automatically; such as migrating forks & redirecting commands such as `clone`, `fetch`, and `push`.

Additionally, one could either **fork** the repository to the new account from the original, or **transfer** the repository to the new account and fork it back to the original account.

***Which of these possible methods will offer the most professional, least confusion, and complete outcome for organizational development?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest transferring the ownership of the repo from your personal account to your organization account.

Forking the repo would create two repos, which sounds like the opposite of what you want. I'm not familiar with the importing feature, but from your description it sounds like it also duplicates the repo.

Check out the "What's transferred with a repository?" header in the docs below; it seems like you'd want to keep all of these relationships as you transfer the repo.

[Github transfer docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/transferring-a-repository)

Comment: transferring the ownership should be the correct way going forward

Comment: I guess I am partially confused about what happens to the original repo when a transfer is initiated. I know that I am automatically a contributor to the project. But don't contributors normally hold a fork? Where will all my commit history appear to have taken place?

Comment: When you transfer the repo, it will belong to the organization. I'm not sure if you'll keep a fork. If not, you can fork it afterward.

Comment: Best way forward here it to test it out. Make a test repo with a few commits and try transferring it to your organization account. Does it satisfy your requirements?